How to calculate realized variance?
I have data about all order book events for a day. I know the midpoint price for each time when something happened to the LOB. If I use all of this data to calculate, I get a high daily realized variance (RV) because I have a lot of elements in the sum. So, how should I use my data to calculate daily variance? Should I use only the first log midpoint price and the last one per day to calculate daily variance?

I think it is common to downsample trade by trade data to, say, 5 minute intervals before computing RV. The articles I read usually say they do this "to remove microstructure noise" i.e. take out the constant short term jiggling that you are seeing that biases the RV upwards.
